# When does Ubuntu Livepatch on a non 24/7 Server

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I have a server that I automatically powerup at 8:00 AM and shutdown at 24:00 PM due to power savings. I'm interessted in Ubuntu LivePatching but I'm not sure how it will perfom with these downtimes as I assume it is intended for 24/7 Servers.

- can I setup when to search for updates, install updates and reboot?

thanks for your feedback.
Michael

Comment: Since you are rebooting your server daily anyway, you seem unlikely to gain any benefit from LivePatch. If you want automated kernel upgrades, then Unattended Upgrades is all you need.

Comment: Related: [Do I need to use canonical Livepatch?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1089584/504066)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, there is a sense in installing kernel live patching on a server Ubuntu installation that is rebooting daily. You decrease the window of opportunity for the hacker attacks that can occur in between the time of publishing of the patch and scheduled reboot.

I have Canonical livepatch installed on my desktop Ubuntu and it does work. At the time of publishing of the patch, it had live patched my kernel which is visible with command:

```
# canonical-livepatch status --verbose
```

The command will say "**patchState: nothing-to-apply**", yet it will list the patched CVE vulnerabilities by CVE numbers when a live patch is issued:

```
# canonical-livepatch status
   client-version: "1"
   architecture: x86_64
   cpu-model: QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.4.0
   last-check: 2016-08-24T19:38:36.793837171Z
   boot-time: 2016-08-24T18:53:56Z
   uptime: 45m4s
   status:
   - kernel: 4.4.0-21.37-generic
     running: true
     livepatch:
       state: applied
       version: "10.1"
       fixes: |-
         * CVE-NNNN-XXXX LP: #NNNNNNN
#
```

You don't set up time when your system is patched as it depends on Canonical making the patch available, at which livepatchd will live patch your kernel ASAP. Reboot is not necessary, and your system will remain patched until the scheduled reboot.

Unless you install new version of kernel when it is available via

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade
```

your system will continue to livepatch kernel upon next power on, right until you do install Linux kernel upgrade and reboot having selected the patched kernel or making it the default.

By default, canonical-livepatch will check if there are new patches made available by Canonical every 60 minutes.

You can change this check interval in minutes by:

```
# canonical-livepatch config check-interval=120
```

Unfortunately, the lowest value is hardcoded to 60 minutes.

Comment: You say "is hardcoded to" -- do you mean "defaults to"? You can set it all the way down to -1 (which means don't check automatically).