# Is Ubuntu Livepatch an antivirus software?

Tags: antivirus

Is livepatch an antivirus program like Windows Defender and McAfee Total Protection and Norton?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to use canonical Livepatch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089584/do-i-need-to-use-canonical-livepatch). See also: [Do I need antivirus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10373)

Answer (score 5):

No, livepatch is not a malware scanner or detector.

It is a tool that allows installing updates and upgrading to a new kernel without rebooting.