# kernel vulnerabilities update and server reboot

Tags: kernel, vulnerability

A few kernel high priority vulnerabilities have been published today: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5317-1

As I'm managing several Ubuntu servers, I was checking a few of them and I'm not quite sure if my servers are protected or not.
All servers are running Ubuntu 20.04 and have unattended-upgrades package properly setup.

I noticed that unattended-upgrades has installed the latest kernel release 5.4.0-104 on several servers (but not on all of them though)... (?)

Does this mean that the servers are protected? or do I absolutely need to reboot them in order to load the new kernel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell, from the command line, whether the machine requires a reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164/how-can-i-tell-from-the-command-line-whether-the-machine-requires-a-reboot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will normally have to reboot to load the new kernel and offer protection.

However, there are certain other options to offer protection without rebooting (known as live-patching).

One option is [Livepatch](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch) by Canonical, which requires `snap` to run (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089584/do-i-need-to-use-canonical-livepatch/)). This option will only offer the most critical kernel updates as livepatches.

Another option is [KernelCare](https://tuxcare.com/live-patching-services/kernelcare-enterprise/) by CloudLinux. My impression is that KernelCare offers a more complete livepatching service. In addition, it also offers livepatching of critical libraries, such as `libc6` and `openssl`.